# Факториал большого числа

Tags: алгоритм

Как посчитать факториал большого числа? К примеру 400!. Я так понимаю, что в стандартные типы такое число не влезет, как это обойти? Если можно пример или сам алгоритм.

Answer (score 4):

Что-то на длинные числа народ потянуло... Зачёты близко?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <gmpxx.h>
using namespace std;
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n;
    stringstream s;
    mpz_class f = 1;
    s.str(argv[1]);
    s >> n;
    for(int i=0; i < n; ) f *= ++i;
    cout << f << endl;
}
```

В результате будет

```
alex@alex-desktop:~$ ./fact 400
```

> `640345228466238952623479703195030058507025830260029594586844
>   459428023971691868314362784786474632646762943505750358568108
>   482981628835174352289619886468029979373416541508381624264619
>   423523070462443250151144486708906627739149181173319559964407
>   095496713452904770203224349112107975932807951015453726672516
>   278778900093497637657103263503315339653498683868313393520243
>   737881577867915063118587026182701698197400629830253085912983
>   461622723045583395207596115053022360868104332972551948526744
>   322324386699484224042325998055516106359423769613992319171340
>   638589965379701478272066063202173794720103213566246138090779
>   423045973606995675958360961587151299138222865785795493616176
>   544804532220078258184008484364155912294542753848035583745180
>   226759000613995601455952061272111929181050324910080000000000
>   000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   00000000000000000000000000000`

Comment: Количество нулей совпало: [400/5]+[400/25]+400/125]=80+16+3=99

Answer (score 1):

Вот примерчик на си: [длинная арифметика](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/big_integer).

Answer (score 1):

Например, [такое](http://algolist.manual.ru/maths/count_fast/factorial.php). А вообще, такие числа в обиходе не встречаются. Например, я когда-то писал факториал на С++, и мне хватало значений вплоть до 137! (тип long long int).

**UPD** В крайнем можно все писать в тип `string` или `char*` а затем применять функции упрощения, если таковые допускаются. Например, [здесь](http://forum.algolist.ru/algorithm-maths/1822-vychislenie-faktoriala.html) рассматривается формула Стирлинга.

**UPD2** И [Википедия](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) в помощь. Только это приближенное вычисление.

Answer (score 0):

Использовать инструменты для арифметики большой точности. Например, в Java это классы `BigInteger` и `BigDecimal`.

Ну или в учебных целях писать эти классы/функции самому.

Answer (score 0):

BigInteger думаю поможет **[тут](https://fox-code.ru/a/vychislenie-faktoriala-kotlin/)**.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -2):

`unsigned long double`.
Также я помню, в одной олимпиаде рассматривался пример с массивом из `integer` (на fpc).

```
type newType: array[0..10000] of integer.  
{использовалось для нахождения чисел Фибоначчи}
```

Comment: При использовании чисел с плавающей точкой будут потери точности. При этом чем больше операций и чем более разные по порядку числа будут в выражениях - тем больше будут потери

Comment: What is usigned long double? 400 факториал в double?)

Comment: Насчет потери точности, то такое никто проверять не будет=) Зато нагрузка на саму систему увеличится в разы при огромном к-ве операций . Хотя всунуть факториал 400 в double, пусть и long))...